# jQuery - credit card date validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the input to automatically parse the numbers to follow the format [MM / YY] like it is done in this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/ajVeON?editors=1010)?

Right now in order for the validation to work, you need to manually enter 5 digits, including a '/' separator entered manually by the user:

```
$("#ExpDate").on("input", function() {
  var expdate = $(this).val();
  if (expdate.length == 5) {
    checkExpDate($(this));
  } else {
    notCorrectInput($(this));
    removeError($(this));
  }
  if (expdate.indexOf("\\") > -1) {
    $(this).val(expdate.replace("\\", "/"));
    expdate = expdate.replace("\\", "/");
  }
  if (expdate.length == 2 && expdate.indexOf("/") > -1) {
    $(this).val("0" + expdate);
  }
});
```

```js
function checkExpDate($ele) {
  var ExpirationInput = (function() {
    var maximumLength = 4;
    var selector;
    var createExpirationInput = function(mainSelector) {
      selector = mainSelector;
      $(selector).keypress(function(e) {
        $(selector).removeClass("has-error");
        if (shouldProcessInput(e, maximumLength, selector)) {
          var inputValue = getInputValue(e, selector);
          if (inputValue.length >= 2) {
            var newInput = inputValue.slice(0, 2) + " / " + inputValue.slice(2);
            $(selector).val(newInput);
          } else {
            $(selector).val(inputValue);
          }
        }
      });
    };
    var parseExpirationInput = function(expirationSelector) {
      var inputValue = getNumber($(expirationSelector).val());
      var month = inputValue.slice(0, 2);
      var year = "20" + inputValue.slice(2);
      return {
        year: year,
        month: month
      };
    };
    return {
      createExpirationInput: createExpirationInput,
      parseExpirationInput: parseExpirationInput
    };
  })();
  var exdate = $ele.val();
  var dateregex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?([0-9]{2})$/;
  if (exdate.length != 0) {
    if (!dateregex.exec(exdate)) {
      activateError($ele);
      $ele.next().text("Date is not valid.");
    } else {
      var today = new Date(),
        someday = new Date();
      someday.setFullYear("20" + exdate.substr(3, 4), exdate.substr(0, 2), 1);
      if (someday < today) {
        activateError($ele);
        $ele.next().text("Card is expired.");
      } else {
        correctInput($ele);
        removeError($ele);
      }
    }
  } else {
    correctInput($ele);
    removeError($ele);
  }
}
$("#ExpDate").on("input", function() {
  var expdate = $(this).val();
  if (expdate.length == 5) {
    checkExpDate($(this));
  } else {
    notCorrectInput($(this));
    removeError($(this));
  }
  if (expdate.indexOf("\\") > -1) {
    $(this).val(expdate.replace("\\", "/"));
    expdate = expdate.replace("\\", "/");
  }
  if (expdate.length == 2 && expdate.indexOf("/") > -1) {
    $(this).val("0" + expdate);
  }
});
$("#ExpDate").keydown(function(e) {
  var exdate = $(this).val();
  if (exdate.length == 5 && keyIsNum(e)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
$("#ExpDate").keydown(function(e) {
  if (
    (e.keyCode > 64 && e.keyCode < 91) ||
    (e.keyCode > 185 && e.keyCode < 191)
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});

function correctInput($ele) {
  $ele.addClass("input-correct");
}

function notCorrectInput($ele) {
  $ele.removeClass("input-correct");
}

function removeError($ele) {
  $ele.next().removeClass("active");
  $ele.removeClass("input-error");
}

function activateError($ele) {
  $ele.addClass("input-error");
  $ele.removeClass("input-correct");
  $ele.next().addClass("active");
}

function keyIsNum(event) {
  console.log(event);
  if (
    (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) ||
    (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105)
  ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function checkIfEmpty($ele) {
  if ($ele.val().length == 0) {
    $ele.addClass("input-error");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```css
.input-error:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.input-error {
  border-color: #DB4F4F !important;
  background-color: #FEF8F8 !important;
}

.input-correct {
  border-color: #75CC72 !important;
  background-color: #F9FEF8 !important;
}

.help-info {
  display: none;
}

.help-info.active {
  display: block;
}

span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text" id="ExpDate" placeholder="MM / YY" />
    <span class="help-info"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is code pen https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/RBxbXP check and let me know

Comment: The formatting is working in your pen, but the validation is not functioning like it does in the snippet.

Comment: Check now https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/RBxbXP

Comment: I need the snippet in the question to be changed. The codepen is just the example of how I want the input to function. The goal is to get the input in the snippet above to work the same way as the input in the codepen.

Comment: The codepen code(which you shared) is best for the validation. the js you have can modify based on my codepen

Comment: I have opened a room for us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code updated to handle the format you mentioned and the validation. here is the codepen link https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/pen/RBxbXP

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var creditly = Creditly.initialize(
      "#ExpDate",
    );
    $(".payment__confirm").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var output = creditly.validate();
   $ele = $("#ExpDate");
   var today = new Date();
      if (output) {
        // Your validated credit card output
        console.log(output);
  if(output.expiration_year > today.getFullYear()){
   $ele.next().show().text("Card is expired.");
  }
  else{
   $ele.next().hide();
  }
      }
    });
  });
});
var Creditly = (function() {
  var getInputValue = function(e, selector) {
    var inputValue = $.trim($(selector).val());
    inputValue = inputValue + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    return getNumber(inputValue);
  };

  var getNumber = function(string) {
    return string.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
  };

  var reachedMaximumLength = function(e, maximumLength, selector) {
    return getInputValue(e, selector).length > maximumLength;
  };

  // Backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter, ., Ctrl+a, Ctrl+c, Ctrl+v, home, end, left, right
  var isEscapedKeyStroke = function(e) {
    return ( $.inArray(e.which,[46,8,9,0,27,13,190]) !== -1 ||
      (e.which == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
      (e.which == 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
      (e.which == 86 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
      (e.which >= 35 && e.which <= 39));
  };

  var isNumberEvent = function(e) {
    return (/^\d+$/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which)));
  };

  var onlyAllowNumeric = function(e, maximumLength, selector) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if (reachedMaximumLength(e, maximumLength, selector) || e.shiftKey || (!isNumberEvent(e))) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };


  var shouldProcessInput = function(e, maximumLength, selector) {
    return (!isEscapedKeyStroke(e)) && onlyAllowNumeric(e, maximumLength, selector);
  };

  var Validation = (function() {
    var Validators = (function() {
      var expirationRegex = /(\d\d)\s*\/\s*(\d\d)/;

      var creditCardExpiration = function(selector, data) {
        var expirationVal = $.trim($(selector).val());
        var match = expirationRegex.exec(expirationVal);
        var isValid = false;
        var outputValue = ["", ""];
        if (match && match.length === 3) {
          var month = parseInt(match[1], 10);
          var year = "20" + match[2];
          if (month >= 0 && month <= 12) {
            isValid = true;
            var outputValue = [month, year];
          }
        }

        return {
          "is_valid": isValid,
          "messages": [data["message"]],
          "output_value": outputValue
        };
      };


      return {
        creditCardExpiration: creditCardExpiration,
      };
    })();

    var ValidationErrorHolder = (function() {
      var errorMessages = [];
      var selectors = [];

      var addError = function(selector, validatorResults) {
        if (validatorResults.hasOwnProperty("selectors")) {
          selectors = selectors.concat(validatorResults["selectors"]);
        } else {
          selectors.push(selector)
        }

        errorMessages.concat(validatorResults["messages"]);
      };

      var triggerErrorMessage = function() {
        var errorsPayload = {
          "selectors": selectors,
          "messages": errorMessages
        };
        for (var i=0; i<selectors.length; i++) {
          $(selectors[i]).addClass("has-error");
        }
  $("#ExpDate").next().show().text("Date is not valid.");
        $("body").trigger("creditly_client_validation_error", errorsPayload);
      };

      return {
        addError: addError,
        triggerErrorMessage: triggerErrorMessage
      };
    });

    var ValidationOutputHolder = (function() {
      var output = {};

      var addOutput = function(outputName, value) {
        var outputParts = outputName.split(".");
        var currentPart = output;
        for (var i=0; i<outputParts.length; i++) {
          if (!currentPart.hasOwnProperty(outputParts[i])) {
            currentPart[outputParts[i]] = {};
          }

          // Either place the value into the output, or continue going down the
          // search space.
          if (i === outputParts.length-1) {
            currentPart[outputParts[i]] = value
          } else {
            currentPart = currentPart[outputParts[i]];
          }
        }
      };

      var getOutput = function() {
        return output;
      };

      return {
        addOutput: addOutput,
        getOutput: getOutput
      }
    });

    var processSelector = function(selector, selectorValidatorMap, errorHolder, outputHolder) {
      if (selectorValidatorMap.hasOwnProperty(selector)) {
        var currentMapping = selectorValidatorMap[selector];
        var validatorType = currentMapping["type"];
        var fieldName = currentMapping["name"];
        var validatorResults = Validators[validatorType](selector, currentMapping["data"]);

        if (validatorResults["is_valid"]) {
          if (currentMapping["output_name"] instanceof Array) {
            for (var i=0; i<currentMapping["output_name"].length; i++) {
              outputHolder.addOutput(currentMapping["output_name"][i],
                  validatorResults["output_value"][i]);
            }
          } else {
            outputHolder.addOutput(currentMapping["output_name"],
                validatorResults["output_value"]);
          }
        } else {
          errorHolder.addError(selector, validatorResults);
          return true;
        }
      }
    };

    var validate = function(selectorValidatorMap) {
      var errorHolder = ValidationErrorHolder();
      var outputHolder = ValidationOutputHolder();
      var anyErrors = false;
      for (var selector in selectorValidatorMap) {
        if (processSelector(selector, selectorValidatorMap, errorHolder, outputHolder)) {
          anyErrors = true;
        }
      }
      if (anyErrors) {
        errorHolder.triggerErrorMessage();
        return false;
      } else {
        return outputHolder.getOutput();
      }
    };

    return {
      validate: validate
    };
  })();

  var ExpirationInput = (function() {
    var maximumLength = 4;
    var selector;

    var createExpirationInput = function(mainSelector) {
      selector = mainSelector
      $(selector).keypress(function(e) {
        $(selector).removeClass("has-error");
        if (shouldProcessInput(e, maximumLength, selector)) {
          var inputValue = getInputValue(e, selector);
          if (inputValue.length >= 2) {
            var newInput = inputValue.slice(0, 2) + " / " + inputValue.slice(2);
            $(selector).val(newInput);
          } else {
            $(selector).val(inputValue);
          }
        }
      });
    };

    var parseExpirationInput = function(expirationSelector) {
      var inputValue = getNumber($(expirationSelector).val());
      var month = inputValue.slice(0,2);
      var year = "20" + inputValue.slice(2);
      return {
        'year': year,
        'month': month
      };
    };

    return {
      createExpirationInput: createExpirationInput,
      parseExpirationInput: parseExpirationInput
    };
  })();


  var initialize = function(expirationSelector) {
    createSelectorValidatorMap(expirationSelector);
    ExpirationInput.createExpirationInput(expirationSelector);
    return this;
  };

  var selectorValidatorMap;

  var createSelectorValidatorMap = function(expirationSelector) {
    var optionValues = {};
    optionValues["expiration_message"] = optionValues["expiration_message"] || "Your credit card expiration is invalid";

    selectorValidatorMap = {};
    selectorValidatorMap[expirationSelector] = {
        "type": "creditCardExpiration",
        "data": {
          "message": optionValues["expiration_message"]
        },
        "output_name": ["expiration_month", "expiration_year"]
      };
  };

  var validate = function() {
    return Validation.validate(selectorValidatorMap);
  };

  return {
    initialize: initialize,
    validate: validate,
  };
})();
```

```css
.input-error:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.input-error {
  border-color: #DB4F4F !important;
  background-color: #FEF8F8 !important;
}

.input-correct {
  border-color: #75CC72 !important;
  background-color: #F9FEF8 !important;
}

.help-info {
  display: none;
}

.help-info.active {
  display: block;
}

span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
}

input.has-error {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #ff7076;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text" id="ExpDate" placeholder="MM / YY" />
    <span class="help-info"></span></div>
</div>
  <button class="payment__confirm"><span>Submit</span></button>
```

Comment: Thanks Aravind. If I un-comment `selectorValidatorMap[creditCardNumberSelector]`, you can see the code works for the other inputs, but your code no longer works. How do I get them both to work when the variable is un-commented? Here is the updated pen: https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/vapREY

Comment: @KyleUnderhill now it's midnight for me.i will check tmrw..in btw I done everything for date validation only. If my answer helped upvote and accept.thanks!

Comment: I have marked your answer complete. Hoping you can help me figure out the issue in my last comment! Thanks again

Comment: @KyleUnderhill hey can you explain your issue in detail on a chat room

Comment: I have migrated to chat. More details there!

Comment: @KyleUnderhill can you share the chat room link?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176990/room-for-kyle-underhill-and-aravind-s